# What causes different fluoresence of PLA from different sources?

Tags: pla, filament

I discovered this by accident while gluing two pieces of 3D printed PLA with UV-curing adhesive.  It's not a problem but I'm curious about why the two materials appearance under UV light is so different.

The PLA came from two different vendors.

[image]

Comment: Can you add information about what color the PLA is (supposed to be). I can't tell if it's white, gray, uncolored (cloudy semi-translucent), or something else.

Comment: Both nominally white though there's a slight but obvious color difference between them when viewed under normal light. The non-fluorescent one looks a little more yellowish. I think one spool was Solutech but not sure.

Comment: The pinkish color on the left one must be a camera artifact; not really like that.

Comment: The "pinkish" color is probably not a camera artifact, but the camera seeing UV as violet due to the way its filters are set up.

Comment: That sounds like a camera artifact to me. The camera is displaying something that's not actually there.

Comment: It is there, just not in a color we normally can see well.